# jList disappears when I add a scrollbar

Tags: java

When I uncomment the 6th and 11th lines below, the jList disappears.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
JList list = new JList();
list.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
list.setBounds(284, 22, 127, 102);
frame.getContentPane().add(list);

//scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVisible(true);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
list.setVisible(true);
//scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

I saw this answer

> add the scrollpane to the container

but I don't know how to do it.

Here is all class:

```
public class Form{
    private String dbDriver= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String dbURL= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/datas";

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtIdPers;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JTextField txtIdToDelete;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Form window = new Form();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Form() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        DefaultListModel listModel= new DefaultListModel();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        JList list = new JList();
        list.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        list.setBounds(284, 22, 127, 102);
        frame.getContentPane().add(list);

        Button btnDisplayAll = new Button("Display All");
        btnDisplayAll.setBounds(341, 205, 70, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDisplayAll);
        displayPersons(btnDisplayAll, textArea, list, listModel);
    }


    private void displayPersons(Button btnDisplayAll, JTextArea textArea, JList list, DefaultListModel listModel){
        btnDisplayAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                ControllerDB controller = new ControllerDB();
                controller.driver= dbDriver;
                controller.url= dbURL;

                try {
                    controller.select("*", "person", "");
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                for(int i=0; i<controller.Selected.size();i++){

                    for(int j=0; j<controller.Selected.get(i).length; j++)
                    {
                        listModel.addElement(controller.Selected.get(i)[j]);

                    }
                    //listModel.addElement("\n");
                }
                list.setModel(listModel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add your `list` to the `scrollPane`

```
scrollPane.add(list)
```

And remove that line

```
frame.getContentPane().add(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the scroll to the container like this:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panelName );
```

Give that a try.

Or try this:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listName);
JpanelName.add(scrollPane);
getContentPane().add(JpanelName);
pack();
```

Keep in mind that scrollbars appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

Maybe try use a [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) instead? it may help? you can then use the code below to add vertical space between components:

```
JpanelName.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(200));
```

Comment: doesn't work. I did from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9z_8yEv7nIc , and it worked, just if its in another class. But in my AppIication Window I don't extend JFrame and even I extend JFrame, doesn't work.

Comment: Does it need to work in another class? and if you need it to be working in the class you want it to what are your errors as well as why is it still a problem?

Comment: Maybe try creating the list before you create the scrollbar? i checked your code and you aren't adding anything to the scrollbar but only declaring it. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way for working with `JList()`, for your question :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ExampJList extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(model);

    public ExampJList() {
        list.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        list.setBounds(284, 22, 127, 102);
        getContentPane().add(list);

        // You can implement different action for popup
        JPopupMenu textArea = new JPopupMenu() {
            public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {
                int row = list.locationToIndex(new Point(x, y));
                if (row != -1) {
                    list.setSelectedIndex(row);
                }
                super.show(invoker, x, y);
            }
        };

        list.setComponentPopupMenu(textArea);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        list.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        setSize(600, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        updater.start();
    }

    final Thread updater = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                model.addElement(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampJList();
    }

}
```

The JFrame, after menu execution, looks like:
[image]